# Reformat Python's vector list results to a single comma delimitted one

Tags: python, arrays, regex

How can I `reformat` the results from a vector array (Python) to a single comma delimitted one?

I have these results:

```
   [ ['44231#0:', '2016/10/11', '11:19:23', '11:19:23', '1', '11:19:24', '11:19:24'
, '0']
 ['44231#0:', '2016/10/11', '12:20:39', '12:20:58', '12:20:59', '12:20:59', '0']
]
```

And I need something like:

```
44231#0:, 2016/10/11, 11:19:23, 11:19:23, 1, 11:19:24, 11:19:24
44231#0:, 2016/10/11, 12:20:39, 12:20:58, 12:20:59, 12:20:59, 0
```

Anyone?

thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simply way will be using two for loop.

```
for d in data:
    s = ''
    for l in d:
        s += l + ', '
    print(s[:-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make a list of strings?  Do:

```
[', '.join(sublist) for sublist in data]
```